# How can I get RealVNC to accept incoming connections in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, vnc

On a Vista machine, I can get the free version of RealVNC to accept incoming connections (i.e., other people can VNC to it).

However, I have not been able to get it to work under Windows 7 - the client gets the below error when trying to connect.

Has anyone else been able to get RealVNC to accept connections under Windows 7?

```
VNC Viewer : Question

read: Connection aborted (10053)
Do you wish to attempt to reconnect to MACHINE_NAME?

Yes   No
```

Comment: I've successfully used [TeamViewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamViewer)'s free client with Windows&nbsp;7. It's worth a look. I've installed the TeamViewer Server version, as it's on my Media server at home. I am not sure about RealVNC, so I apologize I cannot help further with that program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [RealVNC as a server workaround](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2006/12/13/workaround-to-run-vnc-server-in-windows-vista/) for Vista should also work for Windows 7.

Comment: Running as Server (not Service) worked for me as well with Windows 7. Changing to Full Color did not work.

Answer (score 2):

I just figured it out.  The connection will get rejected if the color settings are wrong.  If you change it to Full Colors in the options, it will connect

Comment: [Aaron Dhiman's answer contradicts](http://superuser.com/questions/42855/how-can-i-get-realvnc-to-accept-incoming-connections-in-windows-7/159817#159817) this statement.

Answer (score 1):

On the VNC Server Enterprise Edition E4.5.4, click "Configure" and uncheck "Prompt VNC Server user to approve connections".  I'm running VNC server on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Just to note that the free version of RealVNC does not support Windows 7 so don't bother there. The pay-for products all support it nicely. Or just use Ultra or Tight or something!